# problems allocating memory dynamically to char * []

Tags: c, pointers

My problem is that my program only register the last word in cad[]:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 4

void main()
{
  char *cad[N];

  for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
      char word[100];
      printf("Escribe algo : ");
      scanf("%s",word);
      cad[i] = (char*)malloc((strlen(word)+1)*sizeof(char));
      cad[i] = word;

  }

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      printf("%s\n",cad[i]); //just print the last word registered
}
```

For example, the idea is if `cad[1] = "Hello", ...cad[n] = "Yea"`, all the words are registered in their respective fields, but when I `printf` all the `cad` from `0` to `n-1` all the `cad[i]` just record the last word that is `"yea"`.

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Try `cad[i] = word;` --> `strcpy(cad[i], word);`

Comment: `x = malloc(y), x = z;` If I had a shot of vodka each time I see this, I would have cirrhosis by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `word` variable is allocated on stack and is optimised to be reused in every loop of the for that reads the words.

Having this said, you are overwriting the allocated memory address with the `word`'s address, so you just discard the allocated memory. So every element in `cad` will point to the `word` address, which will hold the last read word.

What you need to do is to copy the contents of word in the allocated space by making use of `strcpy` function:

```c
    strcpy(cad[i], word);
```

Also, a good practice is to `free` your malloc'd memory after finishing using it:

```c
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        free(cad[i]);
    }
```